# Given a time complexity, how do you calculate run time given an n?

Tags: algorithm, time, runtime, big-o, time-complexity

I was given an algorithm and estimated the time complexity T(n) to be 3*n! + 2.

I know that the time required for the algorithm to run when n = 10 is 1 second, and I wish to calculate the run time for n = 20.

I'm a little confused on how to approach this. I assumed since n=10 that I just plug it into T(n), which gives 3*(10!) + 2, which is obviously not 1 (second).

Can anyone give some tips on how to approach this properly? Thanks!

Comment: `(3*10!+2)/k = 1`. `(3*20!+2)/k = x`. Solve for `x`. Then realize that this is just an estimate, the only way to know for sure is to measure.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks for the response. I assume that I am supposed to solve for k in the first equation and then plug it into equation 2 and solve that for x?

Comment: If time complexity is O(3*n!), so for n = 20, it will take years to complete .

Comment: @PhamTrung is right. 670,442,449,629 seconds - which is about 21,259 years...

Answer (score 2):

As @MarkRansom wrote in the comments you would have to solve the equation

```
Runtime(m) / T(m) = Runtime(n) / T(n)
```

for `Runtime(m)`. In this special case, the result is that big (see @shapiro.yaacov's comment) that it doesn't matter, if this value is exact or not.

Let's say your complexity is `T(n) = 2n²` and you measure 1 second for `n = 1000` this leads us to

```
Runtime(2000) = T(2000) ⋅ 1s / T(1000) = 4s
```

But this does not mean, that your algorithm runs in exact 4 seconds. It can be much worse, if your input gets bigger than a specific type of memory. E.g. maybe the input for `n = 1000` fits into the cache. If the input for `n = 2000` does not, it has to be stored in the RAM and so your runningtime will be worse by a factor 50 (just throw in a number, I don't know how much slower RAM compared to L3 cache).
It gets even worse, if you have a giant input that not fits into the RAM and has to be stored on a hard disk.